# Is saving roles in local storage safe in Nuxt Js SSR?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

so I have 1 page for the Admin and Supervisor roles, each role has a different component but still one page, then I make the condition v-if = "role === 'Admin'", and I take the role from local storage.  My question is will it be safe?  then can it be used in SSR?  and will it pass using the unit testing jest?

I have gone too far in working on the project, which I am afraid storing in the local storsge is not safe, thank you. I hope someone helps my question

Comment: Nothing on client side can really be trusted, this includes localStorage, which can be set easily in the console `localStorage.setItem('key', 'value')`.  If security is a concern, use server sessions or tokens to authenticate sensitive requests

Comment: is there anything better?  what if it is stored in cookies?  or you have a better way?

Comment: As I said, if security is a concern, use server sessions or tokens to authenticate sensitive requests.  Also, for Nuxt specifically:  https://auth.nuxtjs.org/